# What does :0 behind names in TensorFlow mean?

Tags: tensorflow

With reference to the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope).

```
foo/v:0
```

What does the `:0` mean?

As I see it, it only appears on variables but not on ops. Is it possible for this to be :1 or even :2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for `:%d` in the codebase, you will find not only the variable has `:0` but also ops: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L317

The `:0` simply means the first output of that node. It is possible to have `:1` or `:2` in some cases.

Comment: Could you show some sample code where `:1`and `:2` are displayed?